# Select option of dropdown and make it not active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, dropdown

I got select :

```
<select class="form-control" id="category_id_select" name="Category_Id">
  @foreach (var category in Model.categories){
    <option value="@category.Id">@category.Name</option>
  }
</select>
```

And I got the input where I set value that must be selected on page load  :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cat_id" value="@Model.CategoryId"/>
```

My js file is :

```
$(document).load(function () {
  $('.combobox').combobox();
  var catid = $("#cat_id").val();
  $("#category_id_select ").val(catid);
  $("#add_prop").click(function () {
    alert(catid);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

I will hide that input and wanna to have not active dropdown with already selected value.Whats solution with jquery?

Comment: What, exactly is your question?

Comment: When you debug this, where/how specifically does it fail?  Does this JavaScript code execute at all?  Are there any errors?  What is the value of `catid`?  Does that value exist in the `select`?

Comment: Select option of dropdown and make it not active? - Thats question

Comment: Value exist in the select

Comment: Weird thing that i got alert and it doesnt work.Any idea why it doesnt work?Just cheked in source,its included.

Comment: @Demsaas: `$(someElement).val(someValue)` is exactly how you'd set a value for a form element.  You're going to have to be more specific about what "doesn't work".  Understand that we can't see your screen or debug your code for you.

Comment: *"not active"* means disabled? If so - disable select - `$("#category_id_select ").val(catid).prop('disabled', true)` and for the input - `var catid = $("#cat_id").attr('type', 'hidden').val()`

Comment: Yeah thanks guys,i just understood that problem in js file,it's doesnt load at all,just tryed to write simply console.log(3) and it doesnt work.

Comment: Problem in bundles,fixing it,and then ill try your code,thanks guys!

Comment: When i changed $(document).load(func) to $(function(){
})
Its started to work,still cant understand why it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the value change that you made :

```
$("#category_id_select").val(catid).change();
//Or  
$("#category_id_select").val(catid).trigger('change');
```

**NOTE :** Remove the extra space you've in your selector :

```
$("#category_id_select ").
______________________^
```

And try to use ready function :

```
$(function(){
     //Your code here
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function () {
    var catid = $("#cat_id").val();
    $("#category_id_select").val(catid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="category_id_select" name="Category_Id">
    <option value="c1">category 1</option>
    <option value="c2">category 2</option>
    <option value="c3">category 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cat_id" value="c3"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work.Looks like problem that js doesnt load correctly.

Comment: Last update helped me,thanks,ill try now to do thing for my dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
**`$(function () {
$('.combobox').combobox();
var catid = $("#cat_id").attr('type', 'hidden').val();
$("#category_id_select").val(catid).change();
$("#category_id_select ").val(catid).prop('disabled', true);`**
```

Thats Soliton!Thanks guys!